# Bootloader Settings for C Drive Windows and SD Card Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, sd-card

I have a 256-gig C Drive for Windows 10 and a 32-gig SD Card for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to install a bootloader (maybe GRUB with a custon skin). Do I just need to do what is normally done on a partitioned C Drive setup, or do I need to make a few more tweaks?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS and both systems must be in same boot mode, otherwise you can only dual boot from UEFI or from BIOS in selecting which drive to boot from. Is SDcard bootable. Some systems do not support boot from SD card. But if in an USB adapter it should work if not able to directly boot.

Comment: So *if* my machine can boot from the SD Card with Ubuntu installed, I need to access the BIOS/UEFI every boot and choose drive from there, and If that's not what I want, I need to install Ubuntu on the main drive? Thanks!

Comment: Are you then just using SD card instead of flash drive as installer? Then instructions are really the same as install from flash drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi